# I want to get data two tables which status is active but there is query is not working

Tags: sql

```
SELECT user.user_id,roles.roles_name,user.first_name,user.last_name,user.email,user.gender,user.password,
user.date_of_birth,user.image,user.home_town,user.status FROM USER INNER JOIN roles ON roles.roles_id = user.roles_id
AND STATUS = 1
```

Comment: We are not a code writing service.

Comment: Are you receiving an error? If so, please share.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
user.user_id,
roles.roles_name,
user.first_name,
user.last_name,
user.email,
user.gender,
user.password,
user.date_of_birth,
user.image,
user.home_town,
user.status 
FROM USER 
INNER JOIN roles 
ON roles.roles_id = user.roles_id
AND user.STATUS = '1';
```

Answer (score -2):

this is the basic join query :

```
select 
  *
from 
  TABLE_A
JOIN
  TABLE_B
ON
  TABLE_A.ID = TABLE_B.ID
```

change your current query following above rules, and it should be working fine